# Clean code with generic func, to prevent repetitive code C#

Tags: c#, generics, repeat

This piece of code is working fine, but seems to me that can be done more elegant with generic func, but I don´t now how to do.

is to big and repetitive

```
result.ForEach(ids =>
             {
                 switch (ids.TaskType.ToUpper())
                 {
                     case "BUGS":
                         if (propertyName == "SpentTimeHours")
                         {
                             TotalBugs += GraphTable
                                          ._Bugs
                                          .Where(x => x.Aid == ids.Aid)
                                          .Select(x => x.SpentTimeHours)
                                          .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0;
                         }
                         if (propertyName == "RemainingTimeHours")
                         {
                             TotalBugs += GraphTable
                                          ._Bugs
                                          .Where(x => x.Aid == ids.Aid)
                                          .Select(x => x.RemainingTimeHours)
                                          .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0;
                         }
                         break;
                     case "TASKS_BUGS":
                         if (propertyName == "SpentTimeHours")
                         {
                             TotalTaskBugs += GraphTable
                                              ._BugTask
                                              .Where(x => x.Aid == ids.Aid)
                                              .Select(x => x.SpentTimeHours)
                                              .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0;
                         }
                         if (propertyName == "RemainingTimeHours")
                         {
                             TotalTaskBugs += GraphTable
                                             ._BugTask
                                             .Where(x => x.Aid == ids.Aid)
                                             .Select(x => x.RemainingTimeHours)
                                             .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0;
                         }
                         break;
                 }
             });
```

Thanks in advance

Jolynice

Comment: Maybe this should better be posted in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you Pikoh, for the advice, I wiil do it.

Comment: Aside from possibly being on a different site and regardless of what site it ends up on, the question needs more information - like detailing the types in play...`GraphTable`, `_Bugs`, `_BugTask`.

Comment: Hi Adam. the GraphTable is a static class that contain static Array Object of type BugTask and Bug.  public static BugTask[] _BugTask;                      public static Bug[] _Bugs; This types have the property Aid (long) and spenttime and remaining time double?

Comment: I don't think this needs to be on code review. There are several more things that need to be posted Such as what is the BugTask definition and what is the Bug definition. Why are your properties starting with `_`. Do both these types have a common interface, because then you can make those LINQ statements either a single extension method or a method

Comment: Hi Callum, this type don´t have a common interface, the underscore  was to identify the private property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this with the following:

```
(ids =>
{
    Func<Bug, int> selector = null;
    IEnumerable<Bug> source = null;
    Action<int> incrementor = null;

    switch (ids.TaskType.ToUpper())
    {
        case "BUGS":
            source = GraphTable._Bugs;
            incrementor = i => TotalBugs + i;   
            break;
        case "TASKS_BUGS":
            source = GraphTable._BugTask;
            incrementor = i => TotalTaskBugs + i; 
            break;
        }
    }

    if (propertyName == "SpentTimeHours")
    {
        selector = b => b.SpenTimeHours;
    }
    else if (propertyName == "RemainingTimeHours")
    {
        selector = b => b.RemainingTimeHours;
    }

    if (selector != null && source != null)
    {
         Incrementor(source.Where(x => x.Aid == ids.Aid)
                           .Select(selector)
                           .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: WHOA , thanks a lot inBetween, clean and cleaver, I stil have much to learn :(

Comment: You can make it even cleaner (less paths & code) by removing the `switch` and creating a Dictionary of `Dictionary<string, Action>` containing the actions to perform for the specific TaskType, then do something like `taskTypeMappingDictionary[ids.TaskType.ToUpper()].Invoke();`, and also a Dictionary of `Dictionary<Predicate<string>, Func<Bug, IEnumerable<T>>` for `propertyName`, then it's one line of `selector = selectorDictionary[propertyName];`

Comment: ColinM, thanks for the advice, I will try also your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an overly easy block of code to simplify. It would be easier if there were a common based type for `BugTask` and `Bug`.

As it stands you can do this:

```
var operations = new Operation[]
{
    new BugOperation() { TaskType = "BUGS", PropertyName = "SpentTimeHours", Source = GraphTable._Bugs, Select = x => x.SpentTimeHours, Incremement = v => TotalBugs += v },
    new BugOperation() { TaskType = "BUGS", PropertyName = "RemainingTimeHours", Source = GraphTable._Bugs, Select = x => x.RemainingTimeHours, Incremement = v => TotalBugs += v  },
    new BugTaskOperation() { TaskType = "TASKS_BUGS", PropertyName = "SpentTimeHours", Source = GraphTable._BugTask, Select = x => x.SpentTimeHours, Incremement = v => TotalTaskBugs += v  },
    new BugTaskOperation() { TaskType = "TASKS_BUGS", PropertyName = "RemainingTimeHours", Source = GraphTable._BugTask, Select = x => x.RemainingTimeHours, Incremement = v => TotalTaskBugs += v  },
};

var query =
    from ids in result
    from operation in
        operations
            .Where(x => x.TaskType == ids.TaskType.ToUpper())
            .Where(x => propertyName == x.PropertyName)
            .Take(1)
    where operation != null
    select new { ids, operation }

foreach (var x in query)
{
    x.operation.Update(x.ids.Aid);
}
```

This means you've got the code that is specific to each combination all in the one spot (the `operations` array) and the rest of the code is purely then execution.

You'll need these supporting classes:

```
private abstract class Operation
{
    public string TaskType;
    public string PropertyName;
    public Action<double> Incremement;

    public abstract void Update(long aid);
}

private class BugOperation : Operation
{
    public IEnumerable<Bug> Source;
    public Func<Bug, double?> Select;

    public override void Update(long aid)
    {
        this.Incremement(
            this.Source
                .Where(x => x.Aid == aid)
                .Select(this.Select)
                .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0);
    }
}

private class BugTaskOperation : Operation
{
    public IEnumerable<BugTask> Source;
    public Func<BugTask, double?> Select;

    public override void Update(long aid)
    {
        this.Incremement(
            this.Source
                .Where(x => x.Aid == aid)
                .Select(this.Select)
                .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0);
    }
}
```